# You don't have permission to access admin (Django, wsgi, Apache)

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi, wsgi

I want to configure my Debian server to provide my **Django** application. Everything is working fine but my **Apache2** is blocking the access to my admin site.

So when I am trying to access **www.mydomain.com/admin** the **Apache2** says that I don't have permission to access that site. I can't get why.

```
Alias /static /etc/website/portal/static
        Alias /media /etc/website/portal/static/media
        Alias /admin /etc/website/portal/static/admin

        <Directory /etc/website/portal/static/admin >
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        <Directory /etc/website/portal/static>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        <Directory /etc/website/portal/static/media>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        <Directory /etc/website/portal/Portal>
                <Files wsgi.py>
                        Require all granted
                </Files>
        </Directory>

        WSGIDaemonProcess portal python-home=/etc/website/ python-path=/etc/website/portal
        WSGIProcessGroup portal
        WSGIScriptAlias / /etc/website/portal/Portal/wsgi.py
```

**The structure of my project on the server:**

```
-etc
---website  'that is my virtualenv'
-----portal 'my project folder'
-------manage.py
-------templates
-------Portal 'main project'
-------SomeApp
-------static
----------admin
-------------'files of admin'
----------img
----------media
----------static
```

I thought that I gave access with configuring following in the admin:

```
Alias /admin /etc/website/portal/static/admin

<Directory /etc/website/portal/static/admin >
         Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I also changed the permissions on the **admin folder** with `chmod 777` and `chown :www-data` but it is still not working.

I don't know if it is relevant but I use a MySQL database.

Thank you for your help ! If some information are missing just let me know it.

**FYI:** I restarted Apache several times ;)

**EDIT: Apache error.log**

```
[Sat Feb 03 12:57:46.159991 2018] [autoindex:error] [pid 1648:tid 140319177287424] [client 188.97.14.161:59095] AH01276:
Cannot serve directory /etc/website/portal/static/admin/: 
No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.cgi,index.pl,index.php,index.xhtml,index.htm) found, 
and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
```

Comment: There is actually no need to explicitly grant /admin access in apache configuration. Review your apache log and you might find the problem. You can also post your log here if you're unable to find the problem.

Comment: that is what I thought too, I will look at the logs and show them to you

Comment: Are you sure it is Apache preventing access to the admin and not Django?

Comment: Thanks for that mention. It is possible.

Comment: @DanielRoseman how can I find out if Django causes this problem ?

Comment: What does the actual error say? How is it formatted?

Comment: added the error.log @DanielRoseman

Comment: I don't understand why you have added that alias. You need to remove it. admin is not a set of static fires, it's a Django app.

Comment: what a stupid mistake thank you @DanielRoseman !

Comment: @Coder949 first of all remove /admin as static from apache configuration and then try again if any error then post the log again

Comment: resolved yet you were right @Sagaryal, thanks !